# Reduce filesize on KITKAT

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, bitmapfactory

I am trying to adapt my code to reduce filesize on KITKAT from LOLLIPOP/M.

Resample function for LOLLIPOP/M:

```
public static Bitmap decodeUri(Context c, Uri[] uri, final int requiredSize) throws FileNotFoundException {
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri[0]), null, o);

            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;

            while(true) {
                if(width_tmp / 2 < requiredSize || height_tmp / 2 < requiredSize)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri[0]), null, o2);
        }
```

Resample function for KITKAT (working ?!?):

```
public static Bitmap decodeUriSingle(Context c, Uri uri, final int requiredSize) throws FileNotFoundException {
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, o);

            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;

            while(true) {
                if(width_tmp / 2 < requiredSize || height_tmp / 2 < requiredSize)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, o2);
        }
```

LOLLIPOP/M code to get the Uri from Bitmap:

```
public Uri[] getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return new Uri[]{Uri.parse(path)};
}
```

KITKAT code to get the Uri from Bitmap (not working):

```
public Uri getSingleImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null); // <----- path is null
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

Debugging it, I saw that the path is null.

I am using it in my `onActivityResult`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

    ........

    ........

    ........

    Uri[] results = null;

    // Check that the response is a good one
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    ...........
    }

    try {
        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(getImageUri(MainActivity.this, decodeUri(MainActivity.this, results, 700)));
        mFilePathCallback = null;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         mFilePathCallback = null;
    }
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    ........

    ........

    ........

    Uri result = null;

    try {
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(getSingleImageUri(MainActivity.this, decodeUriSingle(MainActivity.this, result, 700)));
        mUploadMessage = null;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the path in `getSingleImageUri`is null.

What I did for LOLLIPOP/M to resample the images from Camera and Gallery is working fine, in KITKAT not.

Any help? 
I am a rookie in Android, so please be patient.